# Basic Logon with password hash

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to learn the logon coding and below in the 1st attempt it was working fine except I realize I could just use a `userID` login and any other password to login successfully.

I try to strengthen the logon process in the 2nd attempt but encounter the error message below. I couldn't figure out where I'm getting it wrong.

There is the `$username` & `$passWD` using `filter_has_var` to get the data from logon form. It's not shown below in the codes.

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

**1st attempt:**

```
<?php
$username = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'userName') ? $_POST['userName']: null;
$passWD  = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'pwd') ? $_POST['pwd']: null;

include 'database_conn.php';    // make db connection

$sql = "SELECT passwordHash FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);    // prepare the sql statement

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);     
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); // execute the query
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $passWDHash);

if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    password_verify($passWD, $passWDHash);
    echo "<p>Login successful</p>";
}
else {
    echo "<p>Please try again.</p>";
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); 
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**2nd attempt:**

```
<?php
$username = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'userName') ? $_POST['userName']: null;
$passWD  = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'pwd') ? $_POST['pwd']: null;

include 'database_conn.php';    // make db connection

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND passwordHash =?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);    // prepare the sql statement

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $passWD);     
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); // execute the query

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $passWDHash);

if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    password_verify($passWD, $passWDHash);
    echo "<p>Login successful</p>";
}
else {
    echo "<p>Sorry please try again.</p>";
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); 
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

using the wildcard * is not recommend. probably there are more columns in the table than just the 2 you need?

maby something like:

```
SELECT username,passwordHash FROM users WHERE username = ? AND passwordHash =?
```

Comment: Thanks the error didn't appear ... but somehow with the right username & password it doesn't work